# How many sockets are currently been used on windows 10

Tags: sockets, operating-system, udp

I'm trying to find out how many sockets are currently being used on my machine.
If it's possible, I need an API that returns the exact **number** of sockets being used at any time.

I have tried TCPView, and the command `netstat` for many version, but all I get is a list of connections.

Comment: What do you mean by how many sockets are currently being used on your system? 

There could be client sockets (from your system) and server sockets (on which services are running and listening). What you're getting from netstat output would be having categories - listening (waiting for connection as server socket) and established (client connections).

Comment: I'm interested these in status "ESTABLISHED" at specific local address. but I need the amount of them

Comment: You can get the list of established connections using the command `netstat | findstr ESTABLISHED`. Similarly, you can get the `netstat | findstr CLOSE_WAIT` and `netstat | findstr TIME_WAIT`. You can check more in detail here: https://www.pc-freak.net/blog/check-count-established-connections-linux-windows-netstat-command/.

Comment: The nu,mber of ports in ESTABLISHED state *is* the number of connections being used. You can't count the sockets. Every ESTABLISHED connection is using one at each end, and somewhere there must have been a LISTENING socket, and there could be any number of sockets that haven't been bound yet.

Comment: Suppose another thread/process opens another 50 sockets while your query call is returning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just the amount?

netstat -a -n | find /i "127.0.0.1" | find /I "ESTABLISHED" > t.txt && powershell -command "& Get-Content "t.txt" | Measure-Object -Line"

Replace 127.0.0.1 if needed. On my box it resulted in

```
Lines Words Characters Property
----- ----- ---------- --------
   24
```

Looking at t.txt, it will will show something like:

```
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49672        127.0.0.1:49673        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49673        127.0.0.1:49672        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49674        127.0.0.1:49675        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49675        127.0.0.1:49674        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57354        127.0.0.1:57355        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57355        127.0.0.1:57354        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57356        127.0.0.1:57357        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57357        127.0.0.1:57356        ESTABLISHED
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just interested in the *number* of TCP/UDP sockets in use, have a look at the following APIs:

[`GetTcpStatistics()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-gettcpstatistics), [`GetTcpStatisticsEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-gettcpstatisticsex), [`GetTcpStatisticsEx2()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-gettcpstatisticsex2)

[`GetUdpStatistics()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getudpstatistics), [`GetUdpStatisticsEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getudpstatisticsex), [`GetUdpStatisticsEx2()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getudpstatisticsex2)

But those don't really tell you anything useful, and the stats are global, not per-interface.  There are other APIs that can enumerate the available sockets and retrieve actual details about them (statuses, port numbers, etc), which you can use to fine-tune your searching as needed (eg, ESTABLISHED on IP x Port y):

[`GetTcpTable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-gettcptable), [`GetTcpTable2()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-gettcptable2), [`GetExtendedTcpTable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getextendedtcptable)

[`GetUdpTable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getudptable), [`GetUdp6Table()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getudp6table), [`GetExtendedUdpTable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getextendedudptable)